# Is there a way to "bundle" together airflow operators for re-usability?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have 3 custom operators `AOperator, BOperator, COperator`.

They are commonly used like this -

```
a_data = AOperator(
        task_id="a_data",
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        region=REGION,
        body=body_str_data
    )

b_data = BOperator(
    task_id="b_data",
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    region=REGION,
    dag=dag
)

c_data = COperator(
            task_id="c_data",
            project_id=PROJECT_ID,
            region=REGION,
            dag=dag
)

a_data -> b_data -> c_data
```

While these operators are frequently used by them selves using them in this order is quite common and I would like to be able to call a single "operator" (or something other than an operator, just a single call to something) to basically insert this operator sequence into a dag

```
start = DummyOperator(
    task_id="start",
    dag=dag
)

a_b_c_data = CallToSomething(
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    region=REGION,
    body=body_str_data
)

end = DummyOperator(
    task_id="end",
    dag=dag
)

start -> a_b_c_data -> end
```

This would be for re-usability.  Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can create TaskGroup

```
from airflow.decorators import task_group

@task_group(group_id='a_b_c_data')
def a_b_c_group():
    a_data = AOperator(task_id="a_data", project_id=PROJECT_ID,region=REGION, body=body_str_data     )
    b_data = BOperator(task_id="b_data", project_id=PROJECT_ID,region=REGION, )
    c_data = COperator(task_id="c_data", project_id=PROJECT_ID, region=REGION,)

    a_data -> b_data -> c_data

start -> a_b_c_group() -> end
```